# Detect Browserify broken build before committing/deploying

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, deployment, browserify

I'm using Browserify to bundle up my JS before pushing to my Bitbucket repo, and then using Codeship to test the build and push to Heroku.

I'm using Node/Express to serve my app, and in my `index.jade` I have a `<script />` pointing to `/dist/index.js`.

A couple of times, I've mistakenly pushed my latest code with broken Browserify output, ie. the contents of `/dist/index.js` will be:

`console.error('cannot find module XYZ')`

And I've deployed this to my live app. UH OH.

I've put in a very rudimentary test which gets ran on Codeship which I'm hoping should avoid this in the future:

```
var exit = function() {
    process.exit(1)
}
var success = function() {
    process.exit(0)
}
var fs = require('fs')

var index
try {
    index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../public/dist/index.js', 'utf-8')
} catch (e) {
    exit()
}

if(!index){
    exit()
}

var invalid = index.length < 1000

if(invalid){
    return exit()
}

success()
```

I'm just checking if the file exists, and that the contents of the file is over 1000 characters.

Not sure if there's a specific answer to this, but would be a reasonable approach to making sure broken Browserify output never gets committed/deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Codeship before, but I have used other similar services. You haven't described how you push - I'm going to assume you're using `git`.

With `git`, this becomes easy: write a `pre-push` hook that will abort the push if something fails. Here's an example from a project I'm working on:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the protected branches
#
protected_branches='develop master'

# Check if we actually have commits to push
#
commits=`git log @{u}..`
if [ -z "$commits" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

# is the current branch in the list of protected branchs? if so, then run the
# tests
#
if grep -q "$current_branch" <<< "$protected_branches"; then
    # move into the dir containing the tests
    #
    pushd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/contract >/dev/null
    gulp test
    RESULT=$?
    # back to whatever dir we were in before
    #
    popd >/dev/null
    if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "-------- Failed Tests"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

This is a modified version of a script I found in [this blog post](http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/09/03/git-pre-push/).

Basically, this script checks to see if I'm pushing one of the protected branches and, if so, runs my tests. If those test fail, then the push is aborted.

You could, of course, change the conditions under which the push is aborted. For example, write some code to check & see if your `browserify` bundle is correct and fail if it's not. You mention checking the length of your bundle - maybe something like `length=$(ls -l | cut -c 30-34)` and then check the value of length (sorry, I'm not a real `bash` guru).

The benefit of this approach is that the messed up code never leaves your local machine - you run the test locally and if it fails, the code doesn't get pushed. This is likely to be faster than running in on Codeship's service.